# Image upload library codeigniter missing

Tags: codeigniter-2, helper, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image files in codeigniter . For that I wrote :

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

if($this->load->library('upload', $config)){
echo 'Loaded !';
}else{
echo 'Unable to load';
}

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    echo 'Error';
    //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    echo 'Uploaded';
    //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

But I am getting errors like `Unable to load` `Error`. When I checked my `/application/libraries` directory, its empty. Do I need to write the library `upload` my own or its missing? I am using `CodeIgniter 2.1.4`.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to ask you weather you have enctype="multipart/form-data" and put all you controller and model coding too so i could figure that out and the input file name should be userfile

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to create the library. You can find it at `System/libraries/` directory. However, these are som advices to considere:

1. As @saurabh2836 says, make sure that html form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.
2. `/uploads/` should be writeable, as 755 or 777 permissions.

Also, change `echo 'Error';` by `print_r($error)` in order to see know the "real" error that Codeigniter throws.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create the library. However from your code, I believe that you need to specify the correct path that you would be using to store your files. You have written '/uploads/' instead of './uploads/'. make sure you are using a multipart form in your view as well. Thats the most noticeable problem I can see. Try switching directories and add different paths to test your code and make sure you have read/write access on the folders. Good luck.